# Galilean transformation of magnetic and electric field with magnetic monopole

Tags: electromagnetism, inertial-frames, maxwell-equations, magnetic-monopoles, galilean-relativity

Starting from the lorentz force in presence of a magnetic charge:

$$\vec{F} = q_e(\vec E+\vec v\times \vec B)+q_m(\vec  B - \vec  v\times\vec E)\tag 1$$

by galilean invariance, we should have $\vec F = \vec F'$ (where $\vec F'$ is the lorentz force in an other inertial frame of reference):

$$q_e(\vec E+\vec v\times \vec B)+q_m(\vec  B - \vec  v\times\vec E) = q_e(\vec E'+\vec v'\times \vec B')+q_m(\vec  B' - \vec  v'\times\vec E')\tag 2$$

In electromagnetism (without magnetic charge) we can find the galilean transformation of $\vec E$ and $\vec B$ using an equation similar to (2) (with $q_m=0$) and assuming $\vec v' = \vec v + \vec u$ we can find $\vec E'$ and $\vec B'$ by identifying the different terms in the equation as function of $\vec E$, $\vec B$ and $\vec{u}$. But now, with a magnetic monopole:

$$q_e(\vec E+\vec v\times \vec B)+q_m(\vec  B - \vec  v\times\vec E)=q_e(\vec E'+\vec v\times \vec B'+\vec u\times \vec B')+q_m(\vec  B' - \vec  v\times\vec E'- \vec  u\times\vec E')\tag 3$$

We can't identify $\vec E$ on the left hand side with something on the right hand side.

So, is there no galilean transformation of the field when we consider the existence of a magnetic monopole? At first I thought that the lorentz transformation of the field (and thus the galilean transformation) should be the same with or without monopole  since we still have the covariant formulation:

$${\displaystyle \partial _{\alpha }F^{\alpha \beta }=J_{\mathrm {e} }^{\beta }}~~~~\textrm{ and  }~~~~{\displaystyle \partial _{\alpha }\tilde F^{\alpha \beta }=J_{\mathrm {m} }^{\beta }}\tag 4$$

But because of (3) and the apparent impossibility of identification, I've some doubts.

Comment: Do you have a reference that claims that $F=F'$.?

Comment: It is confusing to use the symbol $a$ for velocity.

Comment: Since $q_m$ and $q_e$ are independent variables, there really are two independent equations.

Comment: I supposed that the lorentz force in 2 different inertial frames of reference is the same, so $F'=F$, is it wrong? And yes! I will change the $\vec a$

Comment: It may be wrong. You should check your assumptions.

Comment: 'We can't identify ⃗ (on the left hand side) with something on the right hand side.' Why not? How do E and B transform?

Comment: Well, with $q_m=0$, by identification, we easily get: $E = E' + u\times B'$ and $B=B'$ but if $q_m\neq 0$, it seems to me that we can't do something similar. To satisfy the equality we should have $E = E' + u\times B'$ and $B=B'$ (for the first parenthesis after $q_e$) and $B = B' - u\times E'$ and $E=E'$ (for the second parenthesis after $q_m$). These equations can't be both satisfied at the same time, so there is a problem right? Maybe because I wrongly assume that there is a transformation of the field that permits $F = F'$ as you said?

Comment: Also, you could set $q_e=0$ and obtain a similar result. As I said there are 2 independent equations. Furthermore, the Galileo transforms of E and B can be found from the Lorentz ones or from som textbook.